# Issue while executing IMPDP command from local server on remote server

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have two linux servers A(local) and B(remote) having SSH key set between them.
I am trying to do the following in my shell script (.sh file)

1. Do EXPDP on local server A, generate the .dmp file.
2. Transfer that file from local server A to remote server B through SSH
3. Then move that file to another folder on remote server B itself.
4. Do IMPDP from local server A on remote server B to load the dump file (which 
   was already there through step 2 and 3) into db of remote server B.

**What works:** moving dmp file from one folder to other on remote server B from local server A.

```
ssh user@remoteServerB /bin/bash <<EOF
mv /path1/file /path2/file
EOF
```

**What not works** -- calling impdp to run on remote server B from local server A

```
ssh user@remoteServerB /bin/bash <<EOF1
impdp userid=${DBUSERNAME}/${DBPASSWORD}@${ORACLE_SID} tables=${TBL_LIST} directory=dir_name dumpfile=dbdump_${PRCSSDT}.dmp logfile=data_pump_dir:dblog_${PRCSSDT}.log table_exists_action=replace
EOF1
```

I have also tried to put the impdp command in .sh file on remote server B and run like following from local server A but without any success.

```
ssh user@remoteServerB /path/load_dmp.sh
```

The error I get is  `impdp: command not found`

Please let me know if you find any way out, I have tried a lot but I am not able to crack this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide the error message to your first failed command, but I assume it is the same.

The `command not found` indicates that the command is not in your standard `PATH`. So login interactively and find out where the command is, then call it with a full path.

You may also need other environment variables. Either find out which ones are needed, or call `bash` with the `-login` option. That option causes `bash` to read the files it reads on login, this should set up the environment you expect, including `PATH`.

Unrelated note:
Instead of

```
ssh user@remoteServerB /bin/bash <<EOF
mv /path1/file /path2/file
EOF
```

you can use

```
ssh user@remoteServerB mv /path1/file /path2/file
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Just to clarify, my first command works (the mv command) on remote server. It's the second command with impdp which is giving me the command not found error. When I login on my remote server B and execute the impdp here as a local command, it works just that it is not working when I am giving this from other server (local server A) .  If the command is not in PATH then it should not have worked when I logged in on remote server B and executed it from there, but as I said, it worked when executed like that.

Comment: When you login, `bash` executes `.profile` and a bunch of other files that are usually used to setup `PATH` and other environment variables. It doesn't when you execute it as just `bash`, but it does when you execute it as `bash -login`.

Comment: could you please elaborate on bash -login? Do you mean I should write bash -login instead of bash?

Comment: Yes, exactly, use `bash -login`.

Comment: Yes it works and I consider this as an answer. Thank you very much.